# PresentModalViewController as soon as app launch from Framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, static-libraries, presentmodalviewcontroller, ios-frameworks

I am creating a framework, which i will add to some of the projects for accomplishing a particular functionality. 
And this framework will need to open a presentModalViewController as soon as the application launches.
To achieve this, i need to know when view of the first view controller of the main app gets loaded, After that, i will add the following functionality inside framework.

```
[firstLoadedViewController presentModalViewController:viewControllerInsideFramework];
```

How to notify the framework that a rootviewcontroller has been assigned to Window and it gets loaded it's view fully? And how to find what is the firstLoadedViewController by writing code inside framework?

Please advice, Thank you.

Comment: can you use key-value observing to see when the rootViewController on the main window is set? Possibly replace the rootViewController with yours?

Comment: Cool idea @AndrewTetlaw, i will try this today and let you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to do all the work from your framework itself then you can try to modify only the main file by replacing the main bundle reference with your bundle reference.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply @Prajwal .I need RootViewController should load from the main app only, After it gets loaded from main bundle, i need my viewcontroller from framework to be presented. ie) self.window.rootViewController = MainControllerFromMainBundle; after some delay, i will present like [mainControllerFromMainBundle presentModalViewController:viewControllerFromFramework]

Comment: after some delay is risky. your app should load a view controller when app calls appDid finish loading with options. although if you want you can use perform selector after delay function here. be sure that you are loading the nib from the bundle using path for resource.

Comment: I will not change any flow in setting RootViewController. It will be done as usual in ApplicationDidnFinishLaunching method. I need after a first root view controller loaded fully, and after came to rest, i will have to present a modal viewcontroller from the RootViewController.

Comment: @Paramasivan Samuttiram Oh I understood your question now. You Want your framework to be notified when the root view is loaded without any association +1 good question. as @ AndrewTetlaw said key value pair is one approach.

Comment: Sure @Prajwal, Thank you. I will try @ AndrewTetlaw's approach this evening and let you guys know.